# use-package with config: function might not be available at runtime

Tags: emacs, compiler-warnings, flycheck

I like using `use-package` for Emacs. Among other things, I have the following in my configuration file:

```
(use-package proced
  :ensure t
  :config
  (proced-toggle-auto-update 1)
  (general-define-key
    :keymaps 'proced-mode-map
    "j"   'next-line
    "k"   'previous-line))
```

Flycheck warns that the function `proced-toggle-auto-update` might not be available at run time. However, the documentation of `use-package` states that all forms following `config:` are evaluated **after** the package is loaded. Is this flycheck warning a false positive then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the function will be available at runtime, eg. the package will have been loaded (since that function is not autoloaded), then you can let the compiler know by declaring the function, eg.

```
(declare-function proced-toggle-auto-update "proced")
```

I don't use `use-package` but presumably the package will have been loaded given the documentation you cite, so yes, this would be a false positive.

In other circumstances you could explicitly autoload a function as well and let the compiler know,

```
(autoload 'proced-toggle-auto-update "proced")
```

These actions assume the library "proced" is on your load-path, eg. `(featurep 'proced)` is non-nil.

Answer (score 1):

The flycheck `emacs-lisp-checker` is using the byte compiler to figure out possible issues with the code, and it needs a little help to figure out things with `use-package`. For my init files with `use-package`, I do two things:

First, I define a directory local variable for my init files (in `.dir-locals.el`):

```
((emacs-lisp-mode . ((flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path . inherit))))
```

With `inherit` set, the `load-path` used by `flycheck` is taken from the current `load-path`, so it can find all the files in various lisp packages.

Second, I have `(require 'use-package)` in each of the separate files in my init. This seems redundant, but it lets flycheck check the files individually, because it can expand the `use-package` macro for better analysis.

This setup seems to avoid most of the warnings coming from `use-package`, except for ones that really matter. It's not tested on your specific configuration, however.

Comment: It does solve my problem and I really appreciate it; it seems a dot is missing which actually is `((emacs-lisp-mode . ((flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path . inherit))))`.

Comment: Oops, you're right! Sorry about that. I corrected the answer to make it easier for future readers.